# Why is there no legal.stackexchange.com?

Tags: feature-request

Seems like it could be a great place to ask general legal questions.

Comment: "I think there should be a new site for XYZ" is not a feature request; it's something to discuss on Area 51. Simply asking if you've overlooked something is definitely not a feature request.

Comment: There would be massive problems with lawyers attempting to give legal advice across all the world's jurisdictions.  There would also be a massive problem finding lawyers to give advice for free:)

Comment: @MartinJames It literally already exists and it's called law.stackexchange.com - not sure why all the hate and down-votes aside from this existing, thanks to Robert Columbia for pointing this out to me.

Comment: Maybe the downvotes are because people think it should have been easy to find on your own. On my browser there's a hamburger menu in the upper right corner with a list of Stack Exchange sites and a search field. When you type "legal" in the search field it comes right up.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is. It is called [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com). The site permits questions on any area of law, but does not permit questions asking for specific legal advice. If you need specific legal advice, you should consult a lawyer qualified to practice in the applicable jurisdiction.